# Reversing a TXT obfuscated with pyArmor

Tags: python

Ok, so.
PyArmor. Apparently, my friend used it to protect some script, except it's not a python script, it's a few TXT files. Is it possible to reverse engineer it so I can see whats in the actual TXT files? I have the:

```
from pytransform import pyarmor_runtime
pyarmor_runtime()
__pyarmor__(__name__, __file__, b'\x50\x59\x41\x52\x4d\etc`, 2)
```

thing still.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can use the same methodology to obfuscate some known text files of yours, maybe as simple as a file containing "hello" and see how to go through reversing it back and recover the contents.

Answer (score 0):

If they're used or evaluated at runtime a debugger should let you see them after they've been loaded. Post the files.

Comment: Here are the 5 txts along with the armor start file at this [link](https://anonfiles.com/FfcbN9wft0/netherwart_rar) here.